# ng-blur in directive template won't callback on parent controller function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive that uses a template with a input field that makes a callback to the parent controller when the input field loses focus so that I can update other values in the parent model. The directive is implementing jQuery autocomplete. I have tried both calling the parent callback function directly as well as calling a function on the local scope that then in turn calls the callback function.

Here is the directive code and the element the directive is applied to. What am I missing?

HTML:

```
<div iptm-ext-lookup extension="button.destination" siteid="vm.buttonInfo.primaryExtSiteID" buttonid="button.identifier" extensionselected="vm.extensionSelected" numberlostfocus="vm.numberLostFocus(buttonid)"></div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module("iptmApp").directive("iptmExtLookup", function () {

    function Controller($scope, $element, $attrs, extensionMgmtService) {
        $scope.getData = function (extension, siteid) {
            return extensionMgmtService.getExtensionInfo(extension, siteid);
        }
    }

    // I bind the $scope to the DOM behaviors.
    function link(scope, element, attributes, controllers) {

        // Setup jquery UI
        element.autocomplete({
            minLength: 3,
            source: [],
            select: function (event, ui) {
                scope.extensionselected(scope.buttonid, ui.item.value, ui.item.extId, ui.item.extLabel);
            }
        });

        //Watcher to update autocomplete list when the input data changes
        scope.$watch('extension', function (value) {
            if (value != null && value.length > 2) {
                scope.getData(value, scope.siteid).success(function (data) {
                    element.autocomplete("option", "source", data);
                }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert(status);
                });
             }
        });
    }

    // Return the directive confirugation.
    return ({
        controller: Controller,
        link: link,
        restrict: "EA",
        replace: true,
        template: '<input type="text" ng-model="extension" ng-blur="lostFocusCallback({ buttonid: $scope.buttonid })" style="width:100px; height:14px;">',
        scope: {
            extension: '=',
            buttonid: '=',
            extensionselected: '=',
            lostFocusCallback: '&numberlostfocus',
            siteid: '='
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your directive is an isolate scope, so you have to go up one layer to get to the parent scope.  Have you tried doing scope.$parent.numberLostFocus(scope.buttonid) ?

Comment: I don't see `number-lost-focus` attribute expecting callback to your directive

Comment: I updated the code above to fix the issue of the attribute for the callback not matching the scope variable. I shouldn't have to walk up to the parent to call the numberlostfocus method. It should be bound in the isolated scope mapping as I understand it. I do the same thing with the extensionselected callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a closer read of the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-)...

> Often it's desirable to pass data from the isolated scope via an expression to the parent scope, this can be done by passing a map of local variable names and values into the expression wrapper fn

You'll need the following

```
<div iptm-ext-lookup ... numberlostfocus="vm.numberlostfocus(buttonid)"></div>
<!--                                  note the argument name ^  -->
```

and in your directive

```
template: '<input ... ng-blur="lostFocusCallback({ buttonid: buttonid })" ...'
```

You didn't need `$scope.buttonid` as

1. The template is already bound to the directive's scope, and
2. There is no `$scope` variable defined in the template

Comment: I have modified the directive and the parent element like below but it still does not call the parent scope function.

Comment: @GordonGudmundson you've changed your code significantly but I think I see the problem. See my updated answer